# form the log file as a table

Tags: powershell, administrator

I have the following code

```
function ping-test($hosts) {
    $conn = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@($hosts)
    [int]$hostsamount = $conn.Count

    foreach($co in $conn)
    {
        $check = Test-Connection $co -Count 3 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $zugriffzeit = $check | select ResponseTime | Measure-Object ResponseTime -Average
        $avg = [system.math]::Round($zugriffzeit.Average)
        $zeit = Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss

        if($check -eq $null)
        {
            $pcre = Write-Output $co
            $pire = Write-Output 'False'
            $zure = $null
        }
        else
        {
            $pcre = Write-Output $co
            $pire = Write-Output 'True'
            $zure = Write-Output "$avg ms"
            $zure = $zure.Replace(' ','')
        }
        [void]$re.Add([PSCustomObject] @{PCName=$pcre;    PingResult=$pire;    Zugriffszeit=$zure;    Zeit=$zeit} )
        **$log = "Host:{0} Ping: {1} Zugriffszeit: {2} Zeit: {3}" -f $pcre, $pire, $zure, $zeit 
        $log >> $logpath**

        [int]$recount = $re.Count 
        [int]$eff = $recount - $hostsamount
        try {
            $re.RemoveRange(0, $eff)
        }
        catch{
            Write-Host $Error
        } 
    }
    return $re
}
```

I use the following code(is in that function)

```
    $log = "Host:{0} Ping: {1} Zugriffszeit: {2} Zeit: {3}" -f $pcre, $pire, $zure, $zeit 
    $log >> $logpath
```

the Question is: I want to form a table with the Colums "Host", "Ping", "Zugriffszeit", and "Zeit".
How can I form this table and save as a .txt or .log file somewhere??

Thx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same data as you're outputting!

To export to csv (if you want to re-use the data programmatically later):

```
$re |Export-Csv $logpath -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want to ever format it in a nice table again, it's as easy as:

```
Import-Csv $logpath |Format-Table
```

---

If you simply want nicely tabulated output in your log file:

```
$re |Format-Table |Out-String |Out-File $logfile
```

Comment: in this case, I should first of all export-CSV and then import it, format a table and output it again, which means there are going to be two files output. Is there any chances to output only one file formatted as a table.

Comment: No, just do `$re |Export-Csv ...`, then still do `return $re` on the last line and it'll still show in the console

Comment: not only in the console, but also I want to have a log file. After Export-csv, the file is hard to read. That's why I want to format a table out of the exporting file. The problem hier is, if I do that like that, there is going to be two files(one of csv and another the log file that i want). How can i format this table and save in just one file

Comment: @keeran Sorry, I misunderstood your question then, see the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

@MathiasR.Jessen showed import and export to csv.

But if you are bound to use .txt or .log files (As the aspect of your question says) then use PSCustomObject and Out-File

```
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      Host = $pcre
      Ping = $pire 
      Zugriffszeit = $zure
      Zeit = $zeit 
    } | Out-File $logpath
```

Later import it like:

```
Get-Content $logpath
```

Comment: Didn't work. Have got this error below: The value "System.Collections.Hashtable" of the type "System.Collections.Hashtable" cannot be converted to the type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject". 
can be converted.

Comment: bro maybe the reason is that you misunderstood me. I have same code to create a table to save values in an array. But now I want to save the table in a log file. Maybe you might further. I wanna thank you for your help too bro. I solved it with export and import csv. Not the best solution but it works for now. Thx again.